# SuperUser doesn't give/prompt root access

Tags: root-access, superuser

I was trying to move `GoogleMaps` on SD-Cards using `Link2SD`.
When I tried to do so I got a message stating

> Link2SD could not obtain root access.
>   if you have root access make sure you respond 'Allow' or 'Grant' to the superuser request

Then I opened `SuperUser` to check the application list. I was surprised to see that there were no apps there! The last time I have checked there were some apps there(`Link2SD`, `BatteryDoctor`, `TerminalEmulator`).

Searching through the net I read that if an app needs root access, it will ask for it. The next step was to see, `SuperUser`'s settings/preferences.

1. The *Automatic Response* is set to *Prompt*
2. *Notifications* are ticked
3. *Notification Type* is set to *Status Bar*
4. *Use Advanced Prompt* isn't checked

Navigating through `Link2SD`, I've noticed that `Link2SD` was updated. The next thing to do was to uninstall it and install it again. The first time I run it, it never prompted me to give it root access.

What may be wrong? Is there a way to give apps root access(by "brutal force")?

Comment: Download Root Checker and see if you still have root. You may have lost it.

Comment: @geffchang: You were right! `RootChecker` stated that my phone wasn't rooted. How could this have happened? Is it possible to become unrooted on it's own? Now I rerooted it and it really asks for root access.

Comment: weird things happen. i've experienced it before too. glad you were able to fix it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Download [Root Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck&hl=en) and see if phone is still rooted. If it isn't rooted anymore, re-root your phone.

Answer (score 2):

Install [SuperSU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu) instead of SuperUser.  Worked for me!